# How can I dynamically crossed cross merge those JSON array on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic, merge

```
var a = [
    {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    {id:'2', age:19, name:'Mark'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson'}
];

var b = [
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'},
    {id:'2', job: 'CEO'}
];

var c = [
    {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'},
    {id:'2', birth: '1999/05/12'},
    {id:'3', birth: '1982/05/12'}
];
```

I want to do like the Result ..

=====================Result========================

```
[

    {id:'1', age:10, name:'Jaden', job: 'webDev', birth: '1998/02/01'}, 
    {id:'1', age:10, name:'Jaden', job: 'webDev2', birth: '1998/02/01'}, 
    {id:'2', age:15, name:'Mark', job: 'CEO', birth: '2000/05/12'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson', job: '', birth: '1982/05/12'}

]
```

I have tried it whole day but still I don't find any solution :(
and it's not the Join and the 'Key' is id.

Comment: can you give us you closest try ?

Comment: @jonatjano, it looks a bit strange ...

Comment: @NinaScholz The strange thing is to use multiple entry for same guy, I would use an array of job but maybe op doesn't have this choice

Comment: So the first two entries are the same guy, same name, same birth date, even the same id (!) but two different jobs? The logic sounds weird

Comment: @JeremyThille it happens that a guy as multiple job, it isn't this weird

Comment: @jonatjano Yes, but you should still use an Array of Jobs, not two entries that only differ in the job field.

Comment: Also, same id is set for multiple entries.

Comment: @Chry007 maybe that a bad conception from OP maybe that's some bad conception from someone else and he can't control

Comment: @jonatjano Sure! I am not trying to finger point. Still needs to be pointed out, so this mistake is not made somewhere else. And the argument was having multiple jobs isn't weird: True, but representing it in this way is. No matter who made the concept.

Comment: by the way @조준현 this is a very good first question, hope all questions were at least this complete from the start :)

Comment: @jonatjano What is weird is the data modelling. You would never have twice the same entry, with the same name and the same ID, with two different jobs. You would have _one_ entry per person, with one ID and one array of two jobs.

Comment: @JeremyThille I completly agree with you (and mentionned it in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a temporary array for collecting all properties by reducing the given arrays with objects.

This proposal is an abstract solution, which means it is not restricted to some given other properties than the common `id`. All other properties are treated without known in advance.

```js
var a = [{ id: '1', age: 18, name:'Jaden' }, { id: '2', age: 19, name: 'Mark' }, { id: '3', age: 38, name: 'Jackson' }],
    b = [{ id: '1', job: 'webDev' }, { id: '1', job: 'webDev2' }, { id: '2', job: 'CEO' }],
    c = [{ id: '1', birth: '2000/02/01' }, { id: '2', birth: '1999/05/12'}, { id: '3', birth: '1982/05/12' }],
    result = [a, b, c].reduce((r, a) => {
        var temp = [],
            template = Object.assign(...Object.keys(a[0]).filter(k => k !== 'id').map(k => ({ [k]: '' })));
        a.forEach(o => {
            var t = r.filter(({ id }) => o.id === id);
            temp.push(...(t.length ? t : [{ id: o.id }]).map(p => Object.assign({}, p, template, o)));
        });
        temp.push(...r
            .filter(({ id }) => !temp.some(t => t.id === id))
            .map(p => Object.assign({}, p, template))
        );
        return temp;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: avoid declaring variable that way (`var a=[], b=[]`) because this syntax declare `b` as a global variable

Comment: Nina your person with `id: '3'` as no job at all while question have `job: ''` in this case, it may no change many thing but add a verfication if he wants to use a method from `String.prototype` on it

Comment: i see no problem here, for global variables. why should i avoid to declare in global space?

Comment: I was going to say *"if you already have a `b` var in your global scope you'll rewrite it"* but after reading the doc the `var` keyword do that anyways so no problem :/

Comment: @jonatjano, i added a template for all keys with a default value.

Comment: there are so many method from ES6 Array's I still didn't take time to learn :p +1

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this :

```js
let a = [
    {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    {id:'2', age:19, name:'Mark'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson'}
];

let b = [
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'},
    {id:'2', job: 'CEO'}
];

let c = [
    {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'},
    {id:'2', birth: '1999/05/12'},
    {id:'3', birth: '1982/05/12'}
];

let res = []

a.forEach(person => {
  let birthDate
  
  // get the birth date of this person from the birth array
  for (let birth of c) {
    if (birth.id === person.id) {
      birthDate = birth.birth
    }
  }
  
  // for each job with this person id create a new entry in the result array
  for (let job of b) {
    if (job.id === person.id) {
      res.push({id: person.id, age: person.age, name: person.name, birth: birthDate, job: job.job})
    }
  }
  
  // if there was no entry for this person (no job) create an entry with no job
  if (res.length === 0 || res[res.length - 1].id !== person.id) {
      res.push({id: person.id, age: person.age, name: person.name, birth: birthDate, job: ''})
  }
  
})

console.log(res)
```

**but as said in comment by many person you should avoid multiple entry almost equals** : prefer this format using array for jobs

```js
let a = [
    {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    {id:'2', age:19, name:'Mark'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson'}
];

let b = [
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'},
    {id:'2', job: 'CEO'}
];

let c = [
    {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'},
    {id:'2', birth: '1999/05/12'},
    {id:'3', birth: '1982/05/12'}
];

let res = []

a.forEach(person => {
  let tmp = {id: person.id, age: person.age, name: person.name}

  // get the birth date of this person from the birth array
  for (let birth of c) {
    if (birth.id === person.id) {
      tmp.birth = birth.birth
    }
  }
  
  
  // for each job with this person id create a new entry in the job array of current person
  tmp.job = []
  for (let job of b) {
    if (job.id === person.id) {
      tmp.job.push(job.job)
    }
  }
  
  res.push(tmp)
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, and it was really useful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

When facing these kind of problems, I always try to cut them up in to more common steps. For this specific case, there's four:

### 1. Grouping by id

You mention you want to join the elements by id. Let's start out by sorting the entries by id then.

#### Generic example

Here's an example of a `groupBy`:

```js
const groupById = xs =>
  xs.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
      if (!acc[x.id]) acc[x.id] = [];
      acc[x.id].push(x);
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );
  
  
console.log(
  groupById(
    [{ id: 1, a: 1 }, { id: 1, b: 2 }, { id: 2, a: 1 } ]
  )
);
```

If the code is hard to understand, have a look at some "how to group an array of objects by a property" answers here on stack overflow.

#### Applied to your data

```js
var names = [
    {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    {id:'2', age:19, name:'Mark'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson'}
];

var jobs = [
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'},
    {id:'2', job: 'CEO'}
];

var births = [
    {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'},
    {id:'2', birth: '1999/05/12'},
    {id:'3', birth: '1982/05/12'}
];


console.log(
  groupById(names),
  groupById(jobs),
  groupById(births)
)



function groupById(xs) {
 return xs.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
      if (!acc[x.id]) acc[x.id] = [];
      acc[x.id].push(x);
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );
};
```

Note how *most* of the groups (arrays) only have **one** element? Only the jobs object has a group of two jobs. Still, it's important all groups are of the same format: an array.

### 2. Merging name, age, job and birth.

Now that we've got groups of elements that can be accessed by their id, we can start thinking about merging them.

#### Generic example

Javascript has logic to merge objects built in! It's `Object.assign`:

```js
console.log(
  Object.assign(
    { },
    { a: 1 },
    { b: 2 },
    { c: 3, d: 4 }
  )
);
```

#### Applied to your data:

```js
console.log(
  Object.assign(
    { id: null, age: null, name: null, job: null },
    { id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    { id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    { id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'}
  )
);
```

Note that we've used a new, empty person as our first parameter to ensure all properties are present!

### 3. Creating the "extra" entries

Now that we've got the first and the last step figured out, we need to come up with sets of objects that have to be merged. First step: group all the data we have for a certain person. Let's make an array of the id `"1"`:

```
const dataForPerson1 = [ namesAndAges["1"], jobs["1"], births["1"] ];
```

We now have a nested array of:

```
[
  [ { name: "Jaden", ... } ],
  [ { job: "webDev", ... }, { job: "webDev2", ... } ],
  [ { birth: "1998/02/01" } ]
]
```

For this array, we need to make all combinations of three objects possible, Luckily, this is again something that can be "abstracted" in to a generic step:

#### Generic example

```js
const combinations = (xs, ys) => 
  xs.reduce(
    (cs, x) => cs.concat(ys.map(y => [y].concat(x))),
    []
  );


console.log(
  [ ["a"], ["b1", "b2"], ["c"] ]
    .reduce(combinations)
)
```

Notice how we go from four entries scattered across three arrays, to two combinations of entries.

#### Applied to your data:

```js
const combinations = (xs, ys) => 
  xs.reduce(
    (cs, x) => cs.concat(ys.map(y => [y].concat(x))),
    []
  );

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  [ 
    [ {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'} ],
    [ {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
      {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'} ],
    [ {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'} ]
  ].reduce(combinations)
,null, 2));
```

If you look at the outcome closely, you can see the right output starting to take shape!

### 4. Looping over all data and generating the outcome automatically

This is where it all comes together. Summarized (**Bold** steps are added now):

- Start with three arrays
- Group each array by `id` property (1)
- **Loop over all found `id` values to find groups of entries** (4)
- Create all combinations (3)
- Join every entry in to one object (2)

Notice that most of the code is not specific to your app or data. The pipeline that we create, with references to the data, is the thing that eventually does the specific work!

```js
// GENERIC UTILITIES
const groupById = xs =>
  xs.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
      if (!acc[x.id]) acc[x.id] = [];
      acc[x.id].push(x);
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );

const combinations = (xs, ys) => 
  xs.reduce(
    (cs, x) => cs.concat(ys.map(y => [y].concat(x))),
    []
  );
  
const allCombinations = xxs => xxs.length === 1
  ? xxs
  : xxs.reduce(combinations);
  
const merge = proto => obs => Object.assign(
   {}, proto,
   ...obs
);

// OUR DATA
const names = groupById([
    {id:'1', age:18, name:'Jaden'},
    {id:'2', age:19, name:'Mark'},
    {id:'3', age:38, name:'Jackson'}
]);

const jobs = groupById([
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev'}, 
    {id:'1', job: 'webDev2'},
    {id:'2', job: 'CEO'}
]);

const births = groupById([
    {id:'1', birth: '2000/02/01'},
    {id:'2', birth: '1999/05/12'},
    {id:'3', birth: '1982/05/12'}
]);

// DATA SPECIFIC HELPERS
const join = id => [ names[id], jobs[id], births[id] ].filter(x => x);

const allIds = new Set([
  ...Object.keys(names),
  ...Object.keys(jobs),
  ...Object.keys(births)
]);

// OUR APP
const result = Array.from(allIds)
  .map(join)
  .map(allCombinations)
  .reduce((xs, ys) => xs.concat(ys)) // flatten
  .map(merge({ id: null, age: null, name: null, birth: null, job: null }))
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```